# Integral of strictly real function has imaginary component

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, summation, real-numbers

Intuitively and informally speaking, $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ is summing all of the values $f(x)$ yields for $x\in [a,b]$.

So it would make sense that if $f(x)$ is strictly real over $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ would also be real. But this is not the case, as can be shown in this example:

$\int_{2}^{3}\frac{x}{(x-4)^{\frac{1}{3}}}dx=1.10976-1.92217i$ according to wolfram. Notice that $\frac{x}{(x-4)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ has no singularities in $[2,3]$ and it is real in $[2,3]$. The fact we have third root instead of "normal root" means we can have a negative value inside it, no need for imaginary numbers.

So I'm just wondering how can this be, what's the intuition behind this phenomenon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very well-documented problem with Wolfram Alpha and also Mathematica. They often do not pick the "correct" root when doing powers. (Correct here meaning the obvious choice you and I would pick.) For example $(-1)^{1/3}$ can be one of three different numbers: $-1$, $e^{\pi i/3}$ or $e^{5\pi i/3}$. Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica will often choose what is known as a primitive root and I think they usually pick the one with the smallest angle, so in this case $e^{\pi i/3}$. A primitive $n$th root $z$ is one in which $z^k\neq 1$ for any $1\le k < n$.

So in your case, $(x-4)^{1/3} = (-(x-4))^{1/3}$ might be $-(4-x)^{1/3}$ (as a real number) or $(4-x)^{1/3}e^{\pi i/3}$ or $(4-x)^{1/3}e^{5\pi i/3}$.

This issue of Mathematica picking the wrong roots causes a lot of issues when doing definite integrals of special functions in Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha. I've documented a large number of cases where they are completely wrong because of choosing the wrong root. There doesn't seem to be any desire on the part of Wolfram to correct these issues (as they've been around for quite some time). Your intuition is correct: the definite integral of a real-valued function on $\Bbb R$ is a real number.

Comment: It's not "wrong", it's just not the root you expect.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think I edited that right as you were typing your comment. You're absolutely right though.

Comment: Cameron: between $1, e^{2\pi i/3}$, and $ e^{4\pi i/3}$, the one with the smallest angle is $1$. But between $-1, e^{5\pi i/3}$, and $e^{\pi/3}$, the one with the smallest angle is $e^{\pi i/3}$, so the issue seems to be that it is a negative number in the root.

Comment: @EricStucky I meant amongst the principal roots.

Comment: The actual rule is very simple.  If $z = r e^{i\theta}$ with $r > 0$ and $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$, the principal branch of $z^\alpha$ is $r^{\alpha} e^{i \alpha \theta}$.

Comment: @EricStucky You're absolutely right about the nomenclature. I seem to have mixed them up in my head.

Answer (score 2):

No, $f(x)$ is not real.  Wolfram is using the principal branch of $z^{1/3}$, which is not real for negative $z$.  If you want to use the real cube root, try
$$- \int_2^3 \dfrac{x}{(4-x)^{1/3}}$$

You can also use the Surd function.  Surd[x,3] gives you the real cube root of $x$.

Comment: I thought the default for wolfram was to use to real cube root. My mistake. Thank you for the input.